# Enabling JDK 1.5 on JBoss

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, java-5

I am designing a web app, I am using JBoss 4.0.5 and have recently came across the need of enabling the use of JDK 1.5 features on JSP pages. I only need it for one of my JSP pages. I know how to enable this feature, basically by removing the comments on the necessary lines on the web.xml file.

Now here is the problem, the rest of my JSP pages have been designed and implemented without the need of this feature.

If I enable this feature, are there risks of my other JSP pages or some of my other content suffering any type of consequences?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: JDK... 1.5? Java *7* is now obsolete, and WildFly itself is now on version **10**. I understand slow upgrade cycles, but at this point, the answer is "use something less than ten years old".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand there are much newer versions out there right now, but I have no choice but to use this old version right now. Still waiting for an answer to my question please.

Comment: @chrylis Legacy is a good reason to keep running old versions. Some libraries just blank out on newer versions.

Comment: Thank you @TT. Legacy is exactly what I was talking about and the reason why I'm running an older version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how it could be a problem. Java is backward compatible, so any version upgrade should always work with old code written using an older version.

We upgraded to Java 6 (from 4) an year ago...everything including our web projects are working fine. We did a web module upgrade to 3.0 in parallel though. Also upgraded JEE to 6.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to work it out without the need of upgrading.